# SharePoint 404 page

Tags: sharepoint

Is the best place set the 404 error page for SharePoint within the web.config customError section or is there a configuration setting on the site collection/ web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please have a read at [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jingmeili/archive/2007/04/08/how-to-create-your-own-custom-404-error-page-and-handle-redirect-in-sharepoint-2007-moss.aspx)

pasted:

1. In your MOSS server, make a copy of
   %systemdrive%\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\sps404.html
   and call it my404.html
2. Create a Virtual Directory in IIS under your MOSS root web application. For example /errors
3. Create your own redirect aspx page, for example /errors/my404redirect.aspx and code your redirect logic in there. This is a normal asp.net page.
4. In my404.html, make the following change:
           STSNavigate("/errors/my404redirect.aspx?oldUrl=" + requestedUrl);
5. Create a Console Application and insert the following code and run it in MOSS server

   *System.Uri webApplicationUri = new Uri(http://MyMOSSServer/);
      SPWebApplication webApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(webApplicationUri);
      webApplication.FileNotFoundPage = "my404.html"; 
      webApplication.Update();*
6. Now when you browse to a page that doesn't exist, you should expect to be brought to the redirected page.

Comment: A note of caution here: search bots that are following old urls won't get to your fancy aspx page (where you presumably redirect if you have a map of old/bad urls) since bots don't tend to execute javascript. I'm still working on a solution for this on my site.

Comment: Brian, the error page helps for SEO results, when a page is not found: you still give something to the bot to continue moving on, and its best if you give something that indexes well to the rest of your site

Comment: Should "http://MyMOSSServer/" be the name of the server or the name of the web site i created in sharepoint?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this is not a valid solution.  The server should be directly serving the page, javascript should not be used to redirect. My $0.02.

Comment: agreed, the best scenario is to have the IIS handle this

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but an alternative mgith be the following url: http://sharepointsmart404.codeplex.com/ - which should still result in a 404 status code so that search engines remove the page from their cache (eventually)