# SharePoint branding of error pages

Tags: sharepoint, branding

How do we customize the error pages for the following in SharePoint:

> Bad request 400
>
> Unauthorized 401
>
> Forbidden 403
>
> Not found 404 (Solved through [SharePoint 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502336/sharepoint-404-page))
>
> Internal Error 500
>
> Not implemented 501
>
> Service not available 503

While I know how to customize the 404 page, how and what is the best way to customize the other error pages listed?

Through web.config? Separate console app? Stsadm commands?

Answer (score 0):

For **SharePoint 2010**, the following blog posts present some solutions to creating custom error pages:

- [Mapping Custom Error Pages for SharePoint 2010 Site](http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/articles/pages/custom-error-pages-for-sharepoint2010-sites.aspx)
- [An Expected Error Has Occurred](http://www.todd-carter.com/post/2010/04/07/an-expected-error-has-occurred/)

The custom error pages can be activated via feature with the following code-snippet:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        if (null != webApp)
        {
            if(!webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.Error, CustomErrorPage))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot create new error page mapping !!");
            }
            webApp.Update(true);
        }
    }


    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        if (null != webApp)
        {
            if (!webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.Error, null))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot reset error page mapping");
            }
            webApp.Update(true);
        }
    }
```

For **SharePoint Server 2007**, the recommended approach is to create a custom HttpModule as explained in the following blog post:

- [Error Handling in MOSS 2007 Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/03/20/error-handling-in-moss-2007-applications.aspx)